# Error 404 with restTemplate.exchange() , but the url works on Postman

Tags: java, spring

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.put("key", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("some key")));
headers.put("token", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("some token")));

HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(headers); 

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(new URI(myUrl), HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, String.class);
```

It runs well when I provide google's page as myUrl. However it will fail when I provide a particular url (which works fine on postman or browser).

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 NOT FOUND
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Comment: what is the particular url?

Comment: calling the api of a website (I can't really mention it)